# Sequence or list type annotation with append

Tags: python, type-hinting

I have the following setting:

```py
class A:
    pass

class B(A):
    pass

def add_element(lst: list[A], el: A) -> None:
    lst.append(el)

lst: list[B] = [B()]
add_element(lst, B())
```

This causes an error with mypy:

```
t.py:11: error: Argument 1 to "add_element" has incompatible type "List[B]"; expected "List[A]"
t.py:11: note: "List" is invariant -- see https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/common_issues.html#variance
t.py:11: note: Consider using "Sequence" instead, which is covariant
```

If I try this instead:

```py
def add_element(lst: Sequence[A], el: A) -> None:
    lst.append(el)
```

I get

```
t.py:10: error: "Sequence[A]" has no attribute "append"
```

I can think of the ways to force this to work, but what is the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use a [`TypeVar`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeVar):

```py
from typing import TypeVar

class A:
    pass

class B(A):
    pass

T = TypeVar('T', bound=A)
def add_element(lst: list[T], el: T) -> None:
    lst.append(el)

lst: list[B] = [B()]
add_element(lst, B())
```

If we try writing code that uses something other than a subclass of A:

```
lst: list[int] = []
add_element(lst, 0)
```

Then mypy will complain:

```
typetest.py:13: error: Value of type variable "T" of "add_element" cannot be "int"  [type-var]
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

Comment: Of course! I was so focused on finding a covariant version of `list` that I forgot the magic of `TypeVar`. Thank you.